# Приоритет последовательности действий

Tags: javascript

Что должно выполниться первым **JSON.parse** или **JSON.stringify?**

Не могу понять порядок выполнения кода.

Обычно же выполнение кода идет сверху вниз?

```js
let obj = {
  name: "Bratok",
  age: 19
};


let user2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); // **Метка**
```

Comment: _Обычно же выполнение кода идет сверху вниз?_ (с) — Движок «читает» код сверху вниз, слева направо. А выполнять может во всех четырех направлениях)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Вот и я думаю сперва выполнится комментарий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правила такие же, как в математике. Сперва отработает то, что в скобках, затем то, что за их пределами. Код:

```
let user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Будет равен коду:

```
let user = JSON.stringify(obj) 
anotherUser = JSON.parse(user)
```

Comment: Благодарю вас =)

Comment: Во-первых, математика немного не при чём. Во-вторых, в большинстве случаев эти варианты кода ведут себя одинаково, но всё же не всегда. Например, можно подсунуть объект `obj = { toJSON() { delete JSON.parse; return {} } }`. А если написать `JSON1.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`, то в первом варианте аргумент не вычислится.

Answer (score 5):

То же самое вы наверняка много раз не задумываясь использовали. Механизм не меняется от того, что там JSON.parse.

Если вместо аргумента функции написано выражение, прежде чем вызвать функцию, нужно выполнить выражение, чтобы узнать, какой аргумент передаем функции.

`console.log( 2 * 3 );` — не удивительно, что выводит 6: Выполнилось выражение `2 * 3`, результат которого передается в виде аргумента `console.log`

`alert( Math.pow(2, 2) );` — Выше было выражение с оператором умножения, здесь - выражение с оператором вызова функции `()`. Сперва будет вызван `pow`, затем результат его вызова передается в вызов `alert()`

То же самое происходит при вызове `JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(obj) );` и при любых других вложенных вызовах функций, «Изнутри наружу».

Answer (score 1):

Конструкция `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` вычисляется следующим образом:

```
JSON
JSON.parse
JSON.parse JSON
JSON.parse JSON.stringify
JSON.parse JSON.stringify obj
JSON.parse JSON.stringify(obj)
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Вот доказательство:

```js
function scope(name) {
  return new Proxy(() => {}, {
    has(x, key) {
      if (key !== Symbol.unscopables) {
        console.log("Resolve:", key)
        return true
      }
    },
    get(x, key) {
      if (key !== Symbol.unscopables) {
        console.log("Get:", key)
        return scope(key)
      }
    },
    apply(x, me, args) {
      console.log("Call:", name)
      return scope()
    },
  })
}

with (scope()) {
  JSON1.parse(JSON2.stringify(obj))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```